# How to create single Wi-Fi network with two devices connected via Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mesh-networking

See the following image:

[image]

The current setup is the black part. Now I want to run a cable from the router to a relatively distant part of the house and place a device at the other end of the cable so that it extends the Wi-Fi network.

If possible, I want both devices to be part of the same Wi-Fi network so that phones, laptops, etc can roam seamlessly between them, without having to reconnect.

What type of device should I place at the other end of the cable? The router was provided by the ISP, I don't think it's anything special and I don't know how much the ISP will allow me to mess with the settings, so I understand that I may need to place another device next to the router.

Comment: Great first question by the way! A model for all others to follow.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a basic **WiFi range extender** (also sometimes called a WiFi repeater). They're extremely affordable. And since you'll be attaching it to your router via ethernet, it's very simple and straightforward. No additional technologies needed.

You can even assign your same SSID, encryption mode, pass phrase and channel if you wish, so your devices will just connect to whichever one has the stronger signal (usually); although many people choose to use a different SSID (e.g., MyWifi and MyWifi_EXT) to differentiate the two.

A more "elegant" solution (albeit more expensive) is to replace your WiFi access points with a mesh network, but in my opinion, it can be overkill for residential use. Simply buying a range extender and wiring it up is quick, easy, and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I checked some range extenders such as the TP-Link RE200 and RE220. Although they do have an Ethernet port, it's meant to be used to connect client devices to the network, not the extender to the router. At least that's how they sell it. The extender connects to the router wirelessly. Can you recommend a range extender that can be used by wiring it to the router? Thanks again!